# reload page while navigation with google navbar package flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I want  the page to reload automatic because the data changes in the database and I want to be there when the user navigate

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the page to automatically refresh when there are changes in the database, so that the user can see the updated information as they navigate through the app. Is that correct?

Comment: exactly ,and I am using sql server